# Degree symbol on Japanese system

Tags: luatex, siunitx, polyglossia, lmodern

I am trying to write a degree symbol for an angle on a Japanese computer running an English version of Windows 7. Consider the following MWE compiled with LuaLaTeX 1.0.4 on TeXLive 2017:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\begin{document}
The angle is \ang{30}.
\end{document}
```

The output of this code is the following string:

[image: The angle is 30r]

By changing the documentclass to report or removing lmodern, I get the correct degree symbol. Why does this happen and is there a way to produce the right character using these packages?

Comment: Can you use $^{\circ}$?

Comment: $^{\circ}$ works fine, but I would prefer to keep using the SI package if possible for consistency.

Comment: You get the same issue with if you load `fontspec` and not `polyglossia`.  There are lots of search results on these things, but i'm not entirely familiar with `xelatex` and not sure how to get the other solutions to work for you.  anyhow, just suggesting that maybe if you find a resolution for a `fontspec` scenario, you might also have a solution in your `polyglossia` scenario.

Comment: Changing `\usepackage{lmodern}` to `\usepackage{fontspec}` does the trick, thank you! I did not know, `lmodern` is automatically loaded with `lualatex`.

Comment: if removing `lmodern` fixes the problem, but `lualatex` and `xelatex` both auto load it, what exactly is going on here?  Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not related to KOMA-Script. With current TeX Live 2018, I get the same result using the standard class `report` instead of `scrreprt`.

You do not need `\usepackage{lmodern}`, because LuaLaTeX already uses Latin Modern as default font. Moreover, the default (without `lmodern`) is using the OpenType Latin Modern fonts. These are unicode fonts containing much more glyphs than the legacy fonts that are used by `\usepackage{lmodern}` and are limited to 256 characters. And LuaLaTeX is prepared to use several of those extra glyphs.

If you load `\usepackage{lmodern}` you switch to the legacy fonts, limited to 256 characters per font. So you should not use `\usepackage{lmodern}`.

BTW: If you would like to use another font but the default Latin Modern, it is recommended to use package `fontspec` and commands like `\setmainfont`, `\setsansfont` etc. to load an OpenType (or at least an Type-1) font. Such fonts can contain much more than 256 characters.

So I would recommend to use either:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\begin{document}
The angle is \ang{30}.
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\begin{document}
The angle is \ang{30}.
\end{document}
```

For extra math features see also package `unicode-math`.